# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
create table Users(
id float(6) primary key,
username VARCHAR(20),
foreign key(id) references Emps(id));

/*inserting records into users table*/
insert into Users (id) select Employee_Id from emps limit 5;

select * from users;/*selecting records from users table*/
```

Problem is

> ```
> create table Users(
> id float(6) primary key,
> username VARCHAR(20),
> foreign key(id) references Emps(id));
> MySQL said: Documentation
> ```
>
> #1005 - Can't create table `Midterm`.`Users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Show the output for `SHOW CREATE TABLE Emps;`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/q9E2Udf

Comment: No screenshots!!! Copy the complete textual output and post it like CREATE TABLE for the table Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the foreign key constraint to work, the type of the `id` column in the `Users` table needs to be the same as that of the `Employee_Id` column in the `emps` table.

So let's say for example that the `Employee_Id` has type `int(11) unsigned`, then that is how you should also specify the type of `id` in `Users`.

(By the way, `float(6)` is a strange primary / foreign key!)